# Problem with displaying graph in userform

Tags: vba, charts

I am trying to display an existing graph (Name: Chart 3) from Sheet3 to userform.

I used the below code, and it pops up error with debugging

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim cchart As Chart
Dim fname As String


Set cchart = Sheets("Sheet3").ChartObjects("Chart 3").Chart
fname = "C:\CBS  Academic\Integrated Strategy Project\Final 
Paper\Temp\temp.gif"
cchart.Export Filename:=fname, filtername:="gif"
Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(fname)
End sub
```

Comment: check for correct sheet name chart name and `fname` (particularly `fname` in the code produced it is broken into 2 lines with out necessary `" &  _` ), i think it will work OK. Tried code with modified sheet and chart name and  `fname`.  found working without any error .

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: The compiler stops at the fourth line (Set cchart = Sheets("Sheet3").ChartObjects("Chart 3").Chart)

Comment: The error is that the object could not be found

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:** (Tested)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim cchart As Chart
Dim fname As String
Set cchart = Sheets("Sheet3").ChartObjects("Chart 3").Chart

fname = "C:\CBS  Academic\Integrated Strategy Project\FinalPaper\Temp\temp.gif" 'check the address again

cchart.Export Filename:=fname, filtername:="gif"
Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(fname)

End sub
```